# No manual entry for interfaces

Tags: server, 20.04, manpage

I was reading through Ubuntu 20.04 [documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-introduction) and in the TCP/IP Configuration section there is a tip about `man interfaces` command. When i try to use it, I get `No manual entry for interfaces`. I tried it on 20.04 Server and 20.04 Desktop, with the same result. I know there is manual on [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/interfaces.5.html), but why can't I access it through terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `interfaces` configuration file and corresponding manpage, provided by the `ifupdown` package, have been superseded in Ubuntu 20.04 and newer releases.

The package is still available in the repositories, but is no longer installed with a stock Ubuntu system.

18.04 and newer releases of Ubuntu use Netplan (in the `netplan.io` package) to assign and configure interfaces.

See http://netplan.io/examples for examples of how to configure your interfaces using /etc/netplan/some_file.yaml instead of /etc/network/interfaces